# How to write to SD Card in Android 6.0 without asking runtime permission?

Tags: java, android

I want to ask - can the app write data to external SD Card in Android 6.0 without asking runtime permissions? I know the the right way is to check, if the user granted such permission for my app. I made small research, and find out that most of all FileMangers in GooglePlay asking these permissions. But ES FileExplorer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) - doesn't ask such permissions and can perform any manipulations with sd card! Does anybody know how do they achieved this? Thanks for help!

This is my gradle code

```
android {
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
compileSdkVersion 22
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
      abortOnError false
  }
}

packagingOptions {
   exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
   exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}


defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}




buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that when you set in your project's Gradle file the compileSdkVersion not bigger than 22.
**Important! When you deploy a version of your app to Google Play store which was compiled against a version bigger than 22, you can never ever switch back to a version below 23. You cannot even switch back to the last stable version if this version used and SDK version lower than 23. You will get an exception in Google Play Store then. It will not allow it.**
(This happened to me some days ago, I accidently set a version bigger than 22, deployed it to Google Play, and suddenly I had lots of crashes because Android 6.0+ didn't have the used permission and I didn't ask for it because it was not implemented in code. But I was also not able to switch back to the previous working version in Google Play. So I had to quickly implement the new permission model but was not even able to test it since I don't have Android 6.0 devices and the emulators are a total crap and slow. Now I have 3 apps in store where I don't know how they behave on Android 6.0+. I get no crashes anymore so I guess my implementation is correct)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check this solution (but in this way, my app never will be available to use the new features from new SDK's?). And in the future if i'll change the sdk version to 23 - will my app be updated in Google Play?

Comment: There is still one issue with building app with api 22 or lower. By default it will have all the permissions enable for Android M and higher that are present in AndroidManifest.xml file. You don't need to do it at runtime. But if user manually removes the permissions from setting then your app will start crashing.

Comment: If you use compile version 22, you app's functionality can not use features of Android 6.0+. That's why your attempt with supressing the new permission model will work for now, even on Android 6.0+ devices, as long as you don't compile against a higher version.
Your app will surely be updated in store if you compile against a version bigger than 22, but you can never ever switch back to a previous version. In my opinion this is a very bad design by Google, so I would suggest to test your version > 22 very good if you decide to use a newer version one time in future.

Comment: Tried to change api level to 22 - but still cannot write files to sd card on 6.0

Comment: Have you maybe set just the target version and not the compiled version?
Maybe you have to completely uninstall and install the app on your test device again to use a clean installation with the old model.

Comment: Should i also change buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' to lower?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does not matter since newer build tools will support older version, so you just get a better compiler and tools.
Can you post your gradle file(s) in the question?

Comment: Seems to be correct. What is exactly the current behavior? Did you get an exception? If so, did you add the permission to your android manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  /> I have this line in my manifest. Got this exception: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/file.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: It seems to be another error which does not have anything to do with your permission problem. It looks for me that you can basically write to external storage, but it just does not find the file.
You can try to omit the permission in your manifest and look if the error is different. If so, your permission problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks! Now everything is working according to your solution